# Ruby: FizzBuzz not working as expected

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble getting an IF statement to produce the results I think they should. I'm not sure why I cannot get the && ("and") conditional to work.

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
  pool = []
    (1..n).each do |x|
        if x % 3 == 0
            pool.push('Fizz')
        elsif x % 5 == 0
            pool.push('Buzz')
        elsif x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
            pool.push('FizzBuzz')
        else
            pool.push(x)
        end
    end
    puts pool
end

fizzbuzz(10)
```

and they results

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What's wrong with your output?  Readers can't tell you what you've done wrong if they don't know the correct output.  Considering that `pool.push('FizzBuzz')` will never be executed, I assume you want `x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0` to be the first condition that is checked, but that has no effect for `n=10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
  pool = []
    (1..n).each do |x|
        if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
            pool.push('FizzBuzz')
        elsif x % 5 == 0
            pool.push('Buzz')
        elsif x % 3 == 0
            pool.push('Fizz')
        else
            pool.push(x)
        end
    end
    puts pool
end
```

When you use if/elsif/elsif/else, it will execute only one of this conditions at time. If x % 3 == 0, then that's it, ruby will no longer enter any of those conditions, that's why fizzbuzz will never be printed.

Comment: So, would the code be more Ruby-like to use a different conditional statement? I'm still not able to get 'FizzBuzz' to show up after moving the && condition to the top of the IF statement.

Comment: Well, I tried this exact code above and when I call fizzbuzz(15) it prints. Please don't tell me you were calling fizzbuzz(10) yet haha...

Comment: Doh! Newbie here...whoops. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The if/else if/else branching only executes one of the code blocks. If a condition is true, then the following block is executed and the program will skip to the end of the if/else statements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another working version, which is a bit cleaner, but as Tiago Farias said, you wont get the 'fizzbuzz' message printed in a range from [1..10], because you don't have a value which will have the rest 0 for both  % 3 and  % 5, the closest will be 15.

```
def fizzbuzz(n)
  @pool = []
  (1..n).each do |x|
    send_no x
  end
  puts @pool
end

def send_no x
  return @pool << 'fizzbuzz' if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0
  return @pool << 'fizz' if x % 3 == 0
  return @pool << 'buzz' if x % 5 == 0
  @pool << x
end

fizzbuzz(10)
```

Comment: your "if x % 3 && x % 5 == 0" doesn't seem to work correctly. When I change it to "if x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0" it works great. Are you supposed to be able to chain the operators like that?

Comment: It was my mistake, sorry I forgot to add the ==